# using .match() to find occurrences of a character in a string. receiving null instead of matching character

Tags: javascript

```
const fdChar = (string, char) => {
  let regex = /char/gi; 
  console.log(string.match(regex)); 
}
fdChar('bacon', 'a');
```

Hello everyone,

New to coding.  Reintroducing myself to regular expressions.  The above function is just a test for what will be implemented into a larger piece of code for a JavaScript coding challenge.  I keep receiving null in the console.  I want to target certain characters in a string.  Am I not able to store the argument value in my regex variable?

function call fdChar('bacon', 'a');

expected console output: 'a';

received output: null

Comment: Your code is matching against the *literal* "char", **not** the contents of the variable `char`.

Comment: ahh gotcha. that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    const fdChar = (string, char) => {
     let regex = new RegExp(char, 'gi');
      console.log(string.match(regex));
     }

     fdChar('bacon', 'a');
```

Here are the changes made:

Instead of /char/gi, I used new RegExp(char, 'gi') to dynamically create a regular expression based on the char parameter.

The g flag in the regular expression stands for global matching (i.e., find all matches rather than stopping after the first match), and the i flag stands for case-insensitive matching.